# building socket.io based server structure

Tags: node.js, socket.io, php

I'm trying to make server side structure for my new project

project will be web application which should be pretty fast

I think that using sockets will be faster than http requests and I don't want to decrease user experience with lots of page reloads. so I'm planning to use socket.io
but I want to write core of application in PHP

so I came up with idea to use Nodejs as server and use PHP-FPM from nodejs to use php
I need your suggestion is it bad idea ? if yes then why ? and if not how can I achieve using php-fpm from nodejs ?

and if you have better idea to build this kind of structure or any other suggestions please tell me

I'm planing to use latest software in all components including php 5.4+ and maybe 5.5 will be released as stable until I finish project

thanks

Comment: My advice is to draw out an architecture diagram. Show where the lines of communication are, any firewalls in the way, any clustering etc. to figure out if your architecture looks sensible on paper. Then try prototyping a vertical slice of it all, end to end from client side script, to the node.js etc. It shouldn't take you too long and should point out some of the "quirks" in your design. Also, by "pretty fast", what kind of NFRs do you have?

Comment: Thank you Jeff, I tried to draw diagram unfortunately it didn't gave me any more information ( I still think that it should work ) by "pretty fast" I mean application should operate like desktop application ( of course some latency is acceptable )

Comment: Having properly defined NFRs will really help. The current definition is a bit wooly.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) as a PHP websockets server, and it's pretty good, very easy to code for; and wouldn't have the overhead of nodejs <--> PHP-FPM

Don't know how much it will scale up with large numbers of users though.

Comment: I want to be ready for lots of users and I don't think Ratchet can scale like PHP-FPM. in case of Ratchet I think I should come up with some mechanism to scale php to multiple processes
does Ratchet provide fallbacks like socket.io ? I mean using flash socket or ajax if websocket is not possible 
anyways thanks for suggestion it was helpful

Comment: Hi I can't make it work for nginx+php -fpm+ ratchet so far, especially how to make ratchet process talk to php-fpm process, can you give some advices ?